# J-Unit Test: Make static void method in final class throw exception

Tags: junit, static, final, void, powermock

I am writing **J-Unit Tests** for my project and now this problem occured:

I am testing a servlet which uses a Utility class (class is final, all methods are static). The used method returns void and can throw an

> IOException (httpResponse.getWriter).

Now I have to force this exception...

I have tried and searched a lot, but all the solutions I found did not worked, because there was `no combination of final, static, void, throw`.

Has anyone did this before?

EDIT: 
Here is the code snippet

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
try {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action.equals("saveRule")) {
        // Some code
        String resp = "blablabla";
        TOMAMappingUtils.evaluateTextToRespond(response, resp);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    TOMAMappingUtils.requestErrorHandling(response, "IOException", e);
}
```

}

Utils Class:

```
public final class TOMAMappingUtils {
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TOMAMappingUtils.class.getName());
private static final Gson GSON = new Gson();

public static void evaluateTextToRespond(HttpServletResponse response, String message) throws IOException {
    // Some Code
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(message));

}
```

}

Test Method:

```
@Test
public void doPostIOException () {
    // Set request Parameters
    when(getMockHttpServletRequest().getParameter("action")).thenReturn("saveRule");
    // Some more code
    // Make TOMAMappingUtils.evaluateTextToRespond throw IOExpection to jump in Catch Block for line coverage
    when(TOMAMappingUtils.evaluateTextToRespond(getMockHttpServletResponse(), anyString())).thenThrow(new IOException()); // This behaviour is what i want
}
```

So as you can see, i want to force the Utils method to throw an IOException, so i get in the catch block for a better line coverage.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now I have to force this exception"? Why? In what context? What are you actually trying to achieve? What does the method do?

Comment: Added some code snippets for a better discription of my problem

Comment: So it sounds like you just need a writer that will throw an IOException, right?

Comment: Yeah, i thought about this already, but the problem is, that this function will be called a second time after i force this IOException and then i will get an IOException i don't want to have...

Comment: With the same writer? Why would it do that? That sounds very odd.

Comment: yeah, sounds strange to me too.
the developer who is responsible for this tried to send information to the FrontEnd with the writer. When an IOException occures, he want to send an error message via the same writer who threw the IOException, this would not work anyway, am i right??

Comment: So think about that. In particular, if you've failed to write a valid response, you're unlikely to be able to write an error response...

Comment: Are you using powermockito framework ?

Comment: thanks, thats what i thought :)

then, could you please tell me:
how do i force the writer to throw an IOEx?

Comment: regularly i am using mockito, but its possible to use PowerMockito :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mock final class, First add it in `prepareForTest`.

```
@PrepareForTest({ TOMAMappingUtils.class })
```

Then mock as static class

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(TOMAMappingUtils.class);
```

Then set expectation as below.

```
PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException())
    .when(TOMAMappingUtils.class,
            MemberMatcher.method(TOMAMappingUtils.class,
                    "evaluateTextToRespond",HttpServletResponse.class, String.class ))
    .withArguments(Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyString());
```

Another way:

```
PowerMockito
    .doThrow(new IOException())
    .when(MyHelper.class, "evaluateTextToRespond", 
             Matchers.any(HttpServletResponse.class), Matchers.anyString());
```

Comment: Did you add @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) on Test class ?

Comment: Thank you very Much :)
The 2. version worked for me

Now i have 100% line coverage *-*